# Upload of WebJob fails with Azure CLI on Linux (process out of memory)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We are trying to use the Azure CLI on linux to upload a WebJob as part of our continuous deployment pipeline.

> azure site job upload -v $WEB_JOB_NAME $WEB_JOB_TYPE run.zip $WEB_SITE_NAME

But the command fails after > 20 mins of waiting on the "Uploading WebJob" step.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Some more info:

- The cli is properly authenticated. We can trigger already existing WebJobs just fine.
- The exact same run.zip uploads successfully from Microsoft Azure Powershell on Windows.
- The zip-file contains a runnable jar, and a small .cmd-script to start it. File size: 30 MB
- We tried setting the verbose-flag, but it does not give any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the xplat-cli. I don't think it's related to linux because I get the same error when I run the xplat-cli on Windows with a zip file that's around 30 MB too. I'd suggest opening an issue for them here https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues

## Workaround:

You can use the cli to get the site creds and then use `curl` to upload the webjob. Here is a little script that would do that.

```sh
# get site config from azure cli
siteConfig=`azure site show $WEB_SITE_NAME -d --json`

# extract publishing username and password for the site
publishingUserName=`echo $siteConfig| python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['config']['publishingUserName'];"`
publishingPassword=`echo $siteConfig| python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['config']['publishingPassword'];"`
siteScmUrl=`echo $siteConfig | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['site']['siteProperties']['properties']['RepositoryUri'];"`

# build the path for the webjob on the server
jobPath="zip/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/$WEB_JOB_TYPE/$WEB_JOB_NAME"
fullUrl=$siteScmUrl$jobPath

# Upload the zip file using curl
curl -XPUT --data-binary @run.zip -u $publishingUserName:$publishingPassword  $fullUrl
```

*You can read more about the webjob REST APIs here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API*

Comment: Good catch, it didn't occur to me to try the client on Windows as I use the Powershell cmdlts there. I had a feeling that this would be a bug, so I have already posted the issue on github, but will fill out with more details. Thanks.

Comment: A little heads-up: To make the curl-command work we needed to add some headers to the request:

 -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="run.cmd"'

where filename is the runnable file within your zip-file.

Comment: I'm assuming you used the `PUT /api/$WEB_JOB_TYPEwebjobs/$WEB_JOB_NAME` api, right?